# LED Turn Signals on older "wink"-style vehicle

Tags: lights, turn-signal

For some background information - I own a fourth-generation Corvette that has an amber 1157 front turn signal bulb with an amber 194 side marker/turn signal bulb (circled in red below).

These lamps are wired such that when the headlights are ON the side signal is inverted from the front signal, i.e. when the turn signals are OFF the side marker signal is ON constantly, but when the turn signal is ON it goes OFF when the front 1157 bulb's brighter filament is ON. This produces a "wink" effect when the turn signal is ON.

I have been trying to convert all of the exterior bulbs to LEDs over the last couple years, even going so far as to remove the old flashers and replace them with solid-state flashers so they can handle the LED bulbs. I cannot, however, figure out any way to replace the front 1157 bulbs without losing proper functionality of the side markers, which have also been converted to LEDs.

Everything works well when the headlights are OFF. I believe the side marker signal is grounded via the "filament" of the front 1157 bulb when the headlights are on, hence why the LED 1157 bulb does not allow the side bulb to work (there is no filament for the side LED to be grounded through). This is what also produces the "wink" effect when the headlights are on.

Finally my question: Is there any way I can retain the use of the side turn signals while also using an LED for the front? I can probably achieve the desired effect by re-wiring the side marker to connect directly to the flasher and ground, but I would like to avoid doing any re-wiring if possible and maybe even keep the "wink" effect.

[image: Front of Corvette with indicator lights marked]